# Java Animation memory issues

Tags: java, animation

I'm somewhat new to the language but I'll be doing a degree next year which includes a Java paper, so I'm running through the language so that I'm not completely useless next year.

I'm trying to mimic the game 'Flappybird' (it was the first thing that came to mind that would require Java graphics).

When I run my code, the Memory builds up quickly and reaches in excess of 4gb and 15% CPU usage. Could someone please explain what is causing this memory leak/issue.

Feel free to leave recommended alternative methods for my painting/graphics. I apologize for how untidy the code is currently.

CODE:

```
 import java.awt.Component;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Animation {
private Image imgBackgroundBottom, imgBackgroundTop;
private int intFrameHeight;
private int intFrameWidth;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Animation();
}

public Animation() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Program Iniatiated");
    JFrame frameAnimation = new JFrame("Animation");
    frameAnimation.setResizable(false);
    frameAnimation.setSize(310, 650);       
    frameAnimation.setVisible(true);
    int Level = 10;
    frameAnimation.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    for (int i = 0; i < frameAnimation.getWidth() + 1; i++) {
        if (i == frameAnimation.getWidth()) {
            //Level--;
            i = 0;
        }
        frameAnimation.add(new AnimationPane(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Level);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    frameAnimation.revalidate();
    }
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {
      private BufferedImage imgBackgroundBottom, imgBackgroundTop,   imgPipeTop, imgPipeBottom;
      private int XPos = 40, YPos = 40;
      private int BackgroundTopWidth, BackgroundTopHeight;
      private int BackgroundBottomWidth, BackgroundBottomHeight;
      private int i = 0;
      public static int yPipe1, yPipe2, yPipe3, yPipe4;
      public static int xPipe1 = -50, xPipe2 = -50,  xPipe3 = -50, xPipe4 = -50;
      public static int runAgain = 1, selectPipe = 0;
      public AnimationPane(int xValue) {
             try {
                 if (imgBackgroundBottom = null ) {
                 imgBackgroundBottom = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/BackgroundBottom.png"));
                 imgBackgroundTop = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/BackgroundTop.png"));
                 imgPipeTop = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/PipeTop.png"));
                 imgPipeBottom = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/PipeBottom.png"));
                 BackgroundTopWidth = imgBackgroundTop.getWidth(null);
                 BackgroundBottomWidth = imgBackgroundBottom.getWidth(null);
                 BackgroundTopHeight = imgBackgroundTop.getHeight(null);
                 BackgroundBottomHeight = imgBackgroundBottom.getHeight(null);
                this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
                i = xValue;
                repaint();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(imgBackgroundTop, 0, 0, getWidth(), BackgroundTopHeight * 2, this);
    //Level Difficult can be adjusted by adjusting thread.sleep count AND adjusting max.variance in randomisation.
    if (runAgain % 170 == 0) {
        selectPipe++;
        if (selectPipe % 4 == 0) {
            yPipe4 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, 312 + 1);
            xPipe4 = 310;
        } else if (selectPipe % 3 == 0){
            yPipe3 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, 312 + 1);
            xPipe3 = 310;
        } else if (selectPipe % 2 == 0) {
            yPipe2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, 312 + 1);
            xPipe2 = 310;
        } else {
            yPipe1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, 312 + 1);
            xPipe1 = 310;
        }
    }
    xPipe1--;
    xPipe2--;
    xPipe3--;
    xPipe4--;
    runAgain++;
    if (xPipe1 < 310  && xPipe1 > -50) {
        g.drawImage(imgPipeTop, xPipe1, yPipe1 - 400, 50, 400, this);
        g.drawImage(imgPipeBottom, xPipe1, yPipe1 + 150, 50, 400, this);
    }
    if (xPipe2 < 310 && xPipe2 > -50) {
        g.drawImage(imgPipeTop, xPipe2, yPipe2 - 400, 50, 400, this);
        g.drawImage(imgPipeBottom, xPipe2, yPipe2 + 150, 50, 400, this);
    }
    if (xPipe3 < 310 && xPipe3 > -50) {
        g.drawImage(imgPipeTop, xPipe3, yPipe3 - 400, 50, 400, this);
        g.drawImage(imgPipeBottom, xPipe3, yPipe3 + 150, 50, 400, this);
    }
    if (xPipe4 < 310 && xPipe4 > -50) {
        g.drawImage(imgPipeTop, xPipe4, yPipe4 - 400, 50, 400, this);
        g.drawImage(imgPipeBottom, xPipe4, yPipe4 + 150, 50, 400, this);
    }
    g.drawImage(imgBackgroundBottom, -i, BackgroundTopHeight * 2, getWidth() * 2, BackgroundBottomHeight * 2, this);
    g.drawImage(imgBackgroundBottom, getWidth() - i, BackgroundTopHeight * 2, getWidth() * 2, BackgroundBottomHeight * 2, this);
}
```

}

My Program for reference:
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMAcm.png)

Comment: First, take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and possibly [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Also, you paint method is very dangerous, painting is done by chaining a series of method calls together to generate the desired result, you shouldn't modify this unless you are VERY, VERY, VERY sure of what you are doing. Instead of overriding `paint`, you should simply override `paintComponent` (and call it's super methd)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should have a "model" which represents the current state of the game (like the players location and any other values you need to keep track off), you would have a "game/main" loop which would, periodically, update the state of the model, based on the inputs and other logic required and then schedule a paint update.  You're painting should not contain any logic other then that which is required to paint the current state of the model

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll read into those now. I've changed paint to paintComponent too.

Comment: By logic, do you mean all types of logic, including if statements?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have a series of panels (you're adding new panels without removing them, so each time you call repaint, it's possible that ALL those panels are been updated), I'd have a single panel, which was capable of simply painting what need to be painted based on the current state of the game. Remember, Swing uses a passive rendering engine, so a painting event could be triggered at any time, this is why we suggest using a Swing `Timer`.  A more complex approach would be to use a `BufferStrategy`, which allows you to take control of the painting process (AKA active painting)

Comment: *"By logic, do you mean all types of logic, including if statements?"* - Any and all game based logic, like collisions and movement. None of this belongs in the painting process, painting is for painting only

Comment: Ok cool. I'll read into timers and rearrange my logic. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and possibly [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Also, your `paint` method is very dangerous, painting is done by chaining a series of method calls together to generate the desired result, you shouldn't modify this unless you are VERY, VERY, VERY sure of what you are doing. Instead of overriding `paint`, you should simply override `paintComponent` (and call it's super method)

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

As a general rule of thumb, you should have a "model" which represents the current state of the game (like the players location and any other values you need to keep track off), you would have a "game/main" loop which would, periodically, update the state of the model, based on the inputs and other logic required and then schedule a paint update.

You're painting should not contain any logic other then that which is required to paint the current state of the model, painting is for painting

Let's have a look at the code...

```
for (int i = 0; i < frameAnimation.getWidth() + 1; i++) {
    if (i == frameAnimation.getWidth()) {
        //Level--;
        i = 0;
    }
    frameAnimation.add(new AnimationPane(i));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(Level);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frameAnimation.revalidate();
}
```

This is kind of weird (and a little bit dangerous).  Because of a fluke of the way the `main` method is called by the JVM when it starts, the loop isn't running in the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, but you should never make these assumptions.  You should be using either a Swing `Timer` or another `Thread` to run this loop within.

Now, there are two major issues.

1. You are adding more and more and more panels on each iteration of the loop
2. You are modifying the state of the UI from outside the context of the EDT, see the first link.  Swing is NOT thread safe and you should NEVER modify it's state from outside of the context of the EDT.

This would seem to be the core source of your problem

Personally, I'd have a single panel, which was capable of simply painting what need to be painted based on the current state of the game. Remember, Swing uses a passive rendering engine, so a painting event could be triggered at any time, this is why we suggest using a Swing Timer.

A more complex approach would be to use a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html), which allows you to take control of the painting process (AKA active painting), which would allow you to use a `Thread` instead, as you control the painting process.

You should also avoid using `static` where possible, `static` is the cause of more problems and issues then just about anything else we see from new developers, it is NOT a cross object communication mechanism.

If you need to share data (like the model between the game loop and the view), then you should pass a reference of it to both

Comment: I am currently implementing a timer and  redoing all my logic. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Adding the Swing Timer fixed all the issues I was having.